# Why is it necessary to set max cookies per domain?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm enabling maintain mode for the website and getting a warning message "Unable to send the cookie. Maximum number of cookies would be exceeded." due to max cookies is 50. This might be a dumb question but I don't understand why is it necessary to set max cookies per domain? What are advantages of this technique? And what is problem if I remove limit max cookies?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting seems to be relateted to the magento framework (https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/193034).

As you can read in https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/277365 :

> ... incompatibility with several more or less outdated browsers, depending on much you increase it.
> Especially IE 11 and lower have the 50 Cookie per domain limit and still a relevant market share.

So I guess the setting defaults to 50 to reach maximum browser compatibility.

Anyway, my personal experience is that you shouldn't extent this limitation as it impacts the UX of the site (as cookies are sent on each request).